# Incorrect navigation bar colour in limited library picker on iOS 15

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to set the colour of the navigation bar in the limited library picker. To do this I have the following lines in `AppDelegate.application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
if (@available(iOS 13, *)) {
    UINavigationBarAppearance *navigationBarAppearance = [UINavigationBarAppearance new];
    navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor;

    [UINavigationBar appearance].standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance;
    [UINavigationBar appearance].scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance;
}

[UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor;
[UINavigationBar appearance].backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor;
```

This sets the colour to green as I would expect on iOS 14:
[image]

But a faded red colour on iOS 15:
[image]

How can I set the colour correctly on iOS 15?

**EDIT:**
Minimum reproducible example (Set up a new iOS project with single view controller and add the NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key to info.plist)

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import PhotosUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(for: .readWrite, handler: { _ in})
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().presentLimitedLibraryPicker(from: self)
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if #available(iOS 13, *) {
            let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
        }

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.green
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Objective-C version of Matt's solution:

```
UIGraphicsImageRenderer * imageRenderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc]initWithSize:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
UIImage *image = [imageRenderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext *context){
    [TOOLBAR_BACKGROUND_COLOUR setFill];
    [context fillRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
}];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: I added what was suggested in the question that I was marked as duplicating, that doesn't solve the issue, therefore this is not a duplicate

Comment: The code is almost verbatim what the duplicate answer suggested

Comment: Added minimum reproducible example, choose "Select Photos..." when prompted

Comment: What does your interface look like?

Comment: I guess my question is, why is the bar not red, In my MRE, the main view controller also shrinks behind the picker, so that is correct. But what is not working correctly is setting the colour

Comment: It is am MRE for the issue, which is the incorrect colour on the picker view

Comment: Okay, so do you think setting a colour is not possible? Because it was on iOS 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to get completely control over a navigation bar's color is to use a background *image*. Make an image renderer. Fill the context with solid red and extract the image from the renderer. Call `setBackgroundImage` on the appearance proxy.

I don't have time to translate the code from Swift to Objective-C so I leave it up to you:

```
    let rend = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:.init(width:100, height:100))
    let im = rend.image {
        con in
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        con.fill(.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
    }
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(im, for: .default)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does solve it, I will add the objective c code in the question for anyone interested

Comment: Cool, don't put it in the question, just edit my answer. :)

Comment: Also note that I'm unclear on why your code _ever_ worked so my answer is a little incomplete. :)

Comment: @matt Hi, do you know if this is also works for PHPickerViewController new API? or this works only in a customized UIIMagePickerViewController library and not the official Apple API?